# How can I remove the button that is clicked and then replace it with another, then remove again?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ok so I'm trying to make so when Button1 is clicked, it gets removed and replaced by Button2. When Button2 gets clicked, I want it to remove button2 and replace it with button1, etc.. Here's my code I have so far (The buttons are functional so that is not the problem.)

```
//Sound Button1
    soundButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.42)
    soundButton.zPosition = 15
    self.addChild(soundButton)
```

Here's the function that runs when Button1 is clicked:

```
 func sound() {

    soundButton.removeFromParent()
    soundButton2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.42)
    soundButton2.zPosition = 15
    self.addChild(soundButton2)

}
```

Here's the function that runs when Button2 is clicked:

```
func sound1() {
    soundButton2.removeFromParent()

    self.addChild(soundButton)

}
```

Lastly, here is my code for the buttons getting clicked in the touchesEnded function:

```
 //Sound1 Button Pressed
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if soundButton.containsPoint(location) {

            sound()

            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                _ = touch.locationInNode(self)



            }


        }

    }

     //Sound1 Button Pressed
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if soundButton2.containsPoint(location) {

        sound1()

            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                _ = touch.locationInNode(self)



            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use a single button and a control state (or other toggle) which determines the different (appearance or) action?

Comment: Assuming I understand the reasoning for this, you would be better off just changing the sprites texture and name when pressed. Then you can just check the sprites name and decide what needs to be done from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the `hidden` property to toggle the visibility of both buttons. Set the one you want displayed to `hidden = false` and the one you want to hide as `hidden = true`

Comment: But the problem is, is that they're on top of each other and they both detect if the user touches in the button

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating this. What you need is just to remove the button which is tapped, and add an appropriate one:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene{

    let soundButton = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.purpleColor(), size:CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))

     let soundButton2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size:CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        soundButton.name = "button1"
        soundButton2.name = "button2"

        soundButton.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))
        soundButton.zPosition = 15
        self.addChild(soundButton)

        soundButton2.position = soundButton.position

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self){

            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

            if node.name == "button1" {

                node.removeFromParent()

                //Not really needed for this example, but a good habit
                if soundButton2.parent == nil {

                    addChild(soundButton2)
                }

            }else if node.name == "button2"{

                 node.removeFromParent()

                //Not really needed for this example, but a good habit
                if soundButton.parent == nil {

                    addChild(soundButton)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other way way would be to subclass a `SKSpriteNode` and make your Button class (Button:SKSpriteNode), set its [userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userInteractionEnabled) property to true, and implement its `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded` methods.

Or you can use [SKAButton](https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKAButton) class which has a lot of different functionalities (mimics the usefulness of UIButton).